# TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to save an email in to a particular drive folder however getting error message

```
TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object
```

Any idea how I can overcome this.

```
function saveGmailToDrive() { 
    var gmailLabels  = "SaveToDrivetest";  
    var driveFolder  = "Emails saved by " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()

    /* Gmail Label that contains the queue */
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) ? 
                    GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(gmailLabels) :
                    GmailApp.createLabel(gmailLabels);

    var threads = GmailApp.search("in:" + gmailLabels, 0, 5);  

    if (threads.length > 0) {    
        /* Google Drive folder where the Files would be saved */
        var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B9Ug3fXvrl5HeGRddddMcE93bkE3Q1k");
        var folder = folders.hasNext() ?
                         folders.next() : 
                         DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);
    }
```

Comment: DriveApp.getFolderById returns a single folder, not an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In general: if the noun after "get" is in plural form, you get an iterator to be used with `hasNext` and `next` methods. If that noun is in singular form, you get a single object. Examples:

- `getFileById` returns **one File**
- `getFiles` returns an iterator
- `getFilesByName` returns an iterator
- `getFilesByType` returns an iterator
- `getFolderById` returns **one Folder**
- `getFolders` returns an iterator
- `getFoldersByName` returns an iterator